# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs and cannot build a project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I'm working with Android Studio.
But when I want to run my project return error:

```
   Error:Execution failed for task ':audiorecordlibrary:processReleaseManifest'.> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

My app gradle and manifest :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.example"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
  final SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION = '23.0.0'
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION"
  compile project(':audiorecordlibrary')
  compile project(':library')
  compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.cleveroad.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/av_app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my audiorecordlibrary gradle and manifest is :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 11
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 2
            versionName "1.0.1"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        //testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.8.4'
    }
    apply from: '../maven_push.gradle'
```

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="republicofgavin.pauseresumeaudiorecorder">

        <application
            tools:replace="android:icon" android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name">

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

and my another library gradle and manifest is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        resourcePrefix "av_"
    }

    dependencies {
        final SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION = '23.0.0'
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        //noinspection GradleDependency
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION"
    }

    apply from: './gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.cleveroad.audiovisualization"/>
```

My project was implemented before I add audiorecordlibrary to my project.

Can anybody help me ??

Comment: Your error says "see logs."  What do your logs say?